# Making a persistent view item in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to make a the first listview item persistent. I've edited my adaptor but sadly it is still destroying the first view and creating a new one. The reason I want to do this is becuase the first content of the list contains navigation views, and changes I make to that view gets removed when the list is reloaded. Does Array adapter have some kind of ondestroy method so i can catch it from there?

Comment: add that view as a header to listview

Comment: Ok thanks @Raghunandan I did not know you could do that, haha.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rag has pointed out using

```
myListView.addHeaderView(View);
```

is the way to do this.